# How to update builtin Excel document properties (document metadata)

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

i am using method below for adding a custom property but it shows Exception if property already exists. i want to add custom properties if it exists it should be update.

Here is Code i am using for adding properties

```
  Excel.Workbook workBk;
  Application _excelApp;

 public void SetDocumentProperty(string propertyName, string propertyValue)
    {
        try
        {
            _excelApp = new Application();
            workBk = _excelApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\12345.xlsx",
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

            object oDocCustomProps = workBk.CustomDocumentProperties;
            Type typeDocCustomProps = oDocCustomProps.GetType();

            object[] oArgs = {propertyName,false,
             MsoDocProperties.msoPropertyTypeString,
             propertyValue};

            typeDocCustomProps.InvokeMember("Add", BindingFlags.Default |
                                       BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null,
                                       oDocCustomProps, oArgs);
            workBk.Save();
        }

        finally
        {
            workBk.Close(false, @"C:\12345.xlsx", null);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workBk);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This one

```
 public void SetDocumentProperty(string propertyName, string propertyValue)
    {
        try
        {
            _excelApp = new Application();
            workBk = _excelApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\12345.xlsx",
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

            object oDocCustomProps = workBk.CustomDocumentProperties;
            Type typeDocCustomProps = oDocCustomProps.GetType();

            object[] oArgs = {propertyName,false,
             MsoDocProperties.msoPropertyTypeString,
             propertyValue};

            typeDocCustomProps.InvokeMember("Add", BindingFlags.Default |
                                       BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null,
                                       oDocCustomProps, oArgs);
        }
        catch
        {
            object customProperties = workBk.CustomDocumentProperties;
            Type customPropertiesType = customProperties.GetType();

            // Retrieve the specific custom property item
            object customPropertyItem = customPropertiesType.InvokeMember("Item",
                BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, customProperties,
                new object[] { propertyName });
            Type propertyNameType = customPropertyItem.GetType();

            propertyNameType.InvokeMember("Value", BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.SetProperty, null,
            customPropertyItem, new object[] { propertyValue });
        }

        finally
        {
            workBk.Save();
            workBk.Close(false, @"C:\12345.xlsx", null);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workBk);
        }

    }
```